# How to merge dataframes after reading from txt

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `txt` file that contains a list of errorIDs, and a dataframe that has all the IDs.. I want to consolidate this list. For example, lets say I have a dataframe (df1) that looks like this:

```
id  value
a1  foo
a2  fo
a3  fi
a4  fum
a5  fe
```

and a error dataframe (df2) that is being read from a txt, and using `to_csv`, i get

```
error_id
a1
a4
a5
```

I want to run something like:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on='error_id')
```

in order to achieve a final outcome of:

```
id  value
a2  fo
a3  fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to merge. Find the `id` in `df1` that isn't in `df2`:

```
df1 = df1[~df1['id'].isin(df2['error_id'])]
```

The tilde (`~`) negates the condition you're checking for.

Comment: Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on='error_id', how='outer', indicator=True)\
   .query('_merge == "left_only"')[['id','value']]
```

Output:

```
   id value
1  a2    fo
2  a3    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way as well:

```
df.where(
    df.merge(df1, left_on='id', right_on='error_id', how='left')
      .error_id
      .isnull())
      .dropna()

   id value
1  a2    fo
2  a3    fi
```